# How to delete an element from a struct array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

lets say i have a structure like this:

```
struct customer{
    int c1;
    int c2;
    int c3;
};
customer phone[10];

phone[0].c1 = 1;
phone[0].c2 = 1;
phone[0].c3 = 1;

phone[1].c1 = 2;
phone[1].c2 = 2;
phone[1].c3 = 2;
```

so my question is how to remove `phone[1]` from the `struct` array?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best you can do is to overwrite it.

This is a built-in array. So the other elements are not initialized. In the same way, once you write something to one of the elements it stays there until the array goes out of scope or you write something else there.

It would be best to do the same with a `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    struct customer {
        int c1;
        int c2;
        int c3;
    };
    customer phone[10];

    phone[0].c1 = 1;
    phone[0].c2 = 1;
    phone[0].c3 = 1;

    phone[1].c1 = 2;
    phone[1].c2 = 2;
    phone[1].c3 = 2;

    std::vector<customer> phonev{{1,1,1},{2,2,2}};
    phonev.erase(phonev.begin()+1);

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can erase an element.